# Filtering with a custom textbox or select control values using jqgrid.lib.web.mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, lib.web.mvc

I am trying to set up a custom search using some `input type="text"` and `select` controls to provide values to post using ajax to the 
    `ActionResult MethodName(JqGridRequest request, PerfilSearchViewModel viewModel)` of the helper and apply the filtering logic of it.

I noticed the `JqGridRequest request.search` property on the server side helper only goes to `true` when the inbuilt `jqgrid` `search icon` is used.

I have set up and analyzed the examples from http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/documentation, but I yet have to make them work without using glass icon, since there is no sample there without it.

Here is another one: [How to pass a jQuery object as a parameter into jqGrid using the lib.web.mvc namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477551/how-to-pass-a-jquery-object-as-a-parameter-into-jqgrid-using-the-lib-web-mvc-nam), where an object to post to the server is created but since the request search property is `false` also using a different button and controls I can't get to use the filtering part of the helper either.

I appreciate if anyone can show me the way to implement the filtering with my custom search controls.

Thank You.

**Update:** I managed to make progress setting up a javascript function that allows me control to perform a customized search on my button click:

```
function mySearch() {

$('#profiles').jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true });
$('#profiles').trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1, current: true }]);

}
```

And on `Lib.Web.Mvc JQGrid` helper I have a parameter to post a value using this:

```
postDataScript: "{ Name: 'profile'}"
```

The latter is a static value of course, so I am aware I can use this variant to make it dynamic:

```
postDataScript: "function() { return { Name: $('#filter').val() }; }"
```

For the *static value works*, but for the dynamic value called with `val()` is always null on the controller.

Can you please tell me how can I get to have the typed value posted?

Comment: For the dynamic approach you can try this: `postDataScript: "{ Name: function() { return $('#filter').val(); } }"`. Also using `$('#profiles').jqGrid('setGridParam', { postData: { ... } });` is a valid option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You very much @tpeczek, I didn't get to see your answer but after I browsed around and read some time more I managed to solve the requirement. I did this:

1) I attached an event to trigger the search on the grid named "profiles" with a function:

```
function search() {
            $('#profiles').jqGrid('setGridParam', { search: true });
            $('#profiles').trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1, current: true }]);
        }

//attaching the function
$(document).ready(function () {        

        $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
            search();
        });

});
```

2) Then I instantiated your Grid helper and passed the model `JQGrid` values using the `postDataScript` attribute:

```
var grid = new Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid.JqGridHelper<MyProject.Model.ViewModel.ProfileFormattedViewModel>("profiles",
        caption: "profiles",
        cellLayout: 5,
        dataType: Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid.JqGridDataTypes.Json,
        footerEnabled: true,
        methodType: Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid.JqGridMethodTypes.Post,
        pager: true,        
        rowsList: new List<int> { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 },
        rowsNumber: 10,
        loadOnce: false,
        width: 750,
        sortingName: "Sorting_Field",
        sortingOrder: Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid.JqGridSortingOrders.Desc,
        url: Url.Action("Grid", "Profile"),
        userDataOnFooter: false,
        viewRecords: true,        
        postDataScript: "{ 'Name': function () { return $('#filter').val(); } , 'State': function () { return $('#state').find('option:selected').val(); } }"
    ).Navigator(new Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid.JqGridNavigatorOptions() { Search = true });
```

3) This basically gave me the control to active the search feature on the `JQGrid` appart of using the "magnifying glass" icon inbuilt with the grid, so the `JqGridRequest` request.Searching property equals true and my `ProfileSearchViewModel` has its property values loaded with the data passed with the `PostDataScript` attribute when both properties are in the **same order**:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Grid(JqGridRequest request, ProfileSearchViewModel viewModel)
    //equals true 
    if (request.Searching) {
      if (viewModel != null)
        filterExpression = ViewModel.GetFilterExpression();
        //etc... (as your sample application goes)

     }
```

@tpeczek, Your library is fantastic!, but lacks documentation, would be nice to find a way to create enough deep and sampled references so it can be more popular and better used with all its wide features.

Comment: No enough time, there is never enough time ;)